# How to access wifi using dongle in a desktop without wireless capability?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, hotspot, dongle

The desktop is a Lenovo K series, 32 bit system having Windows 7 ultimate right now. It doesn't have wireless capability. I have a Beetle dongle which supports HSUPA / HSDPA / WCDMA / EDGE / GPRS / GSM. It also has internal antennae for receiving and sending. Hence I should be able to connect to a mobile hotspot using this dongle in the PC to access internet.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cant do that.  Mobile hotspots use cellular service to connect to the internet and WiFi to connect to computers.  Your dongle works the same way, as it needs cellular service to connect to the internet.  Since the dongle is directly connected to the computer, there is no need for WiFi and does not have it.

You can go to any store and but a USB WiFi dongle and they are very cheap.  Here is an [example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008IFXQFU).  You can then use the USB WiFi dongle to connect to the hotspot.